# Qual a diferença de "in pairs" e "in ipairs" em Lua?

Tags: lua

```
produtos = {
    arroz = 10,
    feijao = 15
}

for produtos, valor in pairs(produtos) do
    print(produtos .. " custa R$" .. valor)
end
```

Retorna:

```
feijao custa R$15
arroz custa R$10
```

Mas quando eu uso o "ipairs" no lugar do "pairs", retorna nada.

Answer (score 5):

O `ipairs` retorna um iterador de pares chave-valor ordenado. Ele só itera a partir de chaves númericas, precisando ser necessariamente sequenciais, começando do 1 e não tendo nenhum furo entre as chaves.

Esse é o motivo do seu loop não funcionar, suas chaves são uma string, fazendo com que retorne um iterador vazio.

Já o `pairs` retorna um iterador de ordem arbitrária, ele funciona independente da chave estabelecida, podendo ser de qualquer tipo.

Veja um exemplo para entender melhor as diferenças:

```
local tbl = { two = 2, one = 1, "alpha", "bravo", [3] = "charlie", [5] = "echo", [6] = "foxtrot" }

print( "pairs:" )
for k, v in pairs( tbl ) do
    print( k, v )
end

print( "\nipairs:" )
for k, v in ipairs( tbl ) do
    print( k, v )
end
```

Saída:

```
pairs:
1   alpha
2   bravo
3   charlie
5   echo
6   foxtrot
one 1
two 2

ipairs:
1   alpha
2   bravo
3   charlie
```

Answer (score 2):

O iterator "pairs" percorre toda a tabela.

O iterator iterator "ipairs" percorre a tabela usando os índices/chaves 1, 2, etc.
Sua tabela não tem chaves 1, 2, etc, suas chaves são "arroz" e "feijão", por isso o iterator não executa nenhuma vez.

O exemplo abaixo com ipairs deve funcionar (aviso: não testei)

```
local val_prod  = { 10, 15 }
local nome_prod = { "arroz", "feijao" }

for i, valor in ipairs(val_prod) do
    print(nome_prod[i] .." custa R$" .. valor)
end
```